# Global vector of vectors empty

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a class with two global vectors. One is a vector of structures and the other is a vector of vectors of structrures. It's like this:

```
class CNewDisplay:
{
protected:

//Vector of structures
struct FP
{
....
}
std::vector<FP> FP_list;

//Vector of vectors of structures
struct INSTRUCTIONS
{...
}

std::vector<INSTRUCTIONS> Instruction_list;
std::vector< std::vector<INSTRUCTIONS> > Past_Instructions;

public:
    std::string loop_planes(..)
    void fill_instruction_vector(...)
```

So, the 1st vector of structures, I initialize in `loop_planes(...)` and use throughout the whole program in the class public functions without any problem. The vector of vectors `Past_Instructions`, I fill in a thread function (that's it's not in the class public functions because it's used in `_beginthread`and it needs to be of type `void(_cdlec*)(void*)` ) :

```
void py_embed (void*data){
...
CNewDisplay dlg;
dlg.fill_instruction_vector(...)
...
}
```

The function that fills the `Past_Instructions`:

```
void CNewDisplay::fill_instruction_vector(...){
    ....
    Past_Instructions.push_back(Instruction_list);
    Instruction_list.clear();
    //The size of the `Past_Instructions` is correct here
}
```

After the `py_embed()` function exits, the `Past_Instructions` is empty.I guess that it's something to do with `void py_embed(void)` not being in the class public functions but I don't understand why since it's the `void fill_instruction_vector(...)` that calls and fills the `Past_Instructions`vector, and since `Past_Instructions`is global. Can someone explain me this please?

Note: Passing the vector to public member of the class does not work.

Comment: I can not see why you have std::vector and then only vector.

Comment: @40two The vectors are not passed to the `fill_instruction_vector()`,they are accessed inside the function. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: From what it seems, `Instruction_list` and `Past_Instructions` are not global at all, but rather members of class `CNewDisplay` with `protected` access. Now in 'py_embed()' you declare a `CNewDisplay` object (i.e., `dlg`) which is destined to live in the local scope of function 'py_embed()' (i.e., after `py_embed()` exits `dlg` doesn't exist anymore). My question is what vectors you except to be fill since `dlg` is "dead"?

Comment: Short version: Your "global" vectors aren't global at all. They're member variables of instances of each `CNewDisplay` object (each object has their own).

Comment: Yes, of course you guys are right,how stupid of me.. So declaring them in cpp file should be enough to solve my problem right?

Comment: Is Past_Instructions supposed to be a shared/combined history from multiple instances of CNewDisplay? If so, you just need to declare Past_Instructions as 'static' and *also* instantiate it inside the .cpp file.